# Using Jstree Select_all() function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

Hi i have jstree component on my website. Im trying to select all of my tree nodes with using select_all() funtion which is

http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=select_all([supress_event])

my jstree id is 'jstree'

Im trying like;

```
  $('#jstree').select_all.jstree();
```

but it is not working
and i also try like

```
  $('#jstree').select_all();
```

and

```
$('#jstree').select_all().jstree();
```

How can i use this function in my script? Thanks alot for helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$('#jstree').jstree('select_all');
```

As requested, I am explaining it.

I've never used jstree, but as far as I could read on the documentation, it extends Jquery, and all the plugins that extend jquery have two ways to call methods, 1 is by return the instance of the plugin example var plugin = $('selector').data('pluginname'); plugin.methodName(); .
Others just simply do $('selector').pluginname('methodName'), which could be the case of jstree.

Comment: Can you provide more explanation to your answer? Generally speaking, code-only answers are considered lower quality.

Comment: It works! but how can i use its suppress event like 'true' or what if it returns some value like array, how can get this array?

Comment: To get the array: var valuesArray = $('#jstree').jstree('select_all'); about the suppress I am not actually know even what that for. :)

Comment: To use the 'suppress event' parameter, use `$('#jstree').jstree('select_all', true);`. You can also add parameters to other methods this way =)